# How to turn off data thresholds in Google Analytics for Firebase

Tags: ios, flutter, google-analytics, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I need help I integrate firebase analytics in my flutter projects. Wrote some custom events and want to work with data from this events, that why i create metrics and dimensions but it doesn't work because I got data thresholds, and got this message:

> Data in a report or exploration may be withheld when Google signals is enabled and you have a low user count in the specified date range.

So, my question is, how can I turn off this data threshold?

Because my app now, using only 5-10 people and I understand that it not enough for analytics but I read docs and found that possible turn off google signal and all should work. Can some one help me with it?

Comment: This is indeed really anoying, makes Analytics all but useless

Answer (score 1):

By default, Google Analytics uses a "User-ID" for tracking users across devices and sessions, that must be provided by the developer. If you are not tracking users by ID however, it appears (based on experience) that events will always have a warning triangle with "thresholding applied", even with a large event count over a long time, say 50k events over a year.

One solution is to [switch to device-only reporting](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630), as it is not subject to thresholding. Of course, if you do track users with a persistent ID, this will not apply to you, in which case you may want to check that the user ID is being set properly so that Google Analytics can determine that the thresholds for reporting are being met with enough users.

If device-only reporting is an option for you, you can change this setting like so:

- **Log in** to [Google Analytics](https://analytics.google.com)
- Go to **Admin** in the lower left corner with a gear icon (not the Configure menu!)
- Select your "**Property**" in the top right area, meaning the project for which you want to make this change. You may only have one which is already selected.
- Select **Reporting Identity**
- Select **Show all**, if visible
- Select **Device-based**
- **Save** your change

Google also provides some instructions on how to do this [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10976610#identity-options).

Finally, I have seen this setting change from device-based to something else as Google changes how data is collected, so you may need to revisit this setting and re-confirm device-based.

Comment: very good solution , worked for me

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the thresholds that Google Analytics uses in its reports.

Your only option to get access to this data is to enable the integration between Analytics and BigQuery in your Firebase project, and then perform your own reporting on the BigQuery data.