# Firebase Analytics for Flutter not showing about 99% of events

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

### TL;DR

Firebase shows about 1% of events, and rest to events simply doesn't show in Firebase Analytics dashboard.

### Full problem

I finally made my Flutter app works with Firebase Analytics, and in Debug mode I've been seeing all my events.

Then I installed my app on my device in release mode.
Initially, nothing was shown, thus I thought I missed something.

I added SHA1 key, rebuild the app, and... nothing works again.

Then I noticed some event - so I thought - maybe there was some delay in Firebase?

Then again, nothing.... and then again few events.

[image]
[image]

These 2 above pictures shows that there was some activity.

But when I opened my app, I did way more things, I visited more screens, and I've been using the app more than 1 minute. I also I have a button that sends `dummy_event` (that works perfectly in Debug mode). None of these other events were recorded in Firebase.

Comment: For more accurate testing go up to alpha/beta (android) or testflight (ios), it takes a while for events to be counted. If possible share an example of an event that is not counted.

Comment: Few `screen_view`s were not counted (plus few custom events like `myentityname_created`) Also as you can see from the image, it shows Realtime View, and it's about 20minutes old (the single bar is 20 minutes "away"). What's the point of Realtime if it's delaying/missing events from release build?

Comment: Take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271881/how-to-turn-off-data-thresholds-in-google-analytics-for-firebase.

Comment: Is your screenView event done like this `await analytics.logScreenView(screenClass: screenClass, screenName: screenName);`? This is the correct way to count a screen event according to the doc.

Comment: It is. Also please note that all this works fine in Debug mode. And my events are there after 24hours. What's missing is the Realtime view and Users in last 30 minutes (missing majority of my sessions).

Comment: For testing purpose, you can on/off the event logging in debug or release mode importing flutter/foundation.dart like if(kReleaseMode) { await analytics.logScreenView(screenClass: screenClass, screenName: screenName); }

Comment: Could this be your issues?

Issue Tracker: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/8098